# Cannot read property after assigning ejs variable to js

Tags: javascript, json, express, ejs

For whatever reason, this code returns a type error in the if statement. Cannot read property product.thumbgallery1 of undefined.

```
var urlArray= [];
    var product = '<%- product %>';
     console.dir(product);


                for (var count = 1; count < 6; count++) {
                    var stringCount = count.toString();
                     if ( typeof product.data["product.thumbgallery" + stringCount].value.main.url === 'undefined' ) {
                         null
                     } else {
                            urlArray.push( product.data['product.thumbgallery' + stringCount].value.main.url )
                     }
                 }
```

Interestingly enough, this code works:

```
var lol = '<%- product.data["product.thumbgallery1"].value.main.url %>';
    console.log(lol);
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: Can you provide us the JSON for `product`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pass object to ejs you need use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
 var product = <%- JSON.stringify(product) %>;
```